# NANDROID backup without warranty voiding?

Tags: rooting, backup, nandroid

Is there any way to do a 100% NANDROID backup without any warranty voiding?

If there is a way to **temporarily root** or install TWRP, that would be fine too

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964607

I do rooting experiments (eg. processor clock battery runtime) on cheaper phones, but I better do not sacrifice the more expensive ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to do a 100% NANDROID backup without any warranty voiding?

Nandroid means using custom recovery (TWRP or CWM ) and in turn unlocking boot loader (on most devices). Whether this voids warranty or not depends on a) OEM b) Country / region specific laws. It depends on case by case so a general answer is not possible but in most branded devices it would void warranty

> If there is a way to **temporarily root** or install TWRP, that would be fine too

Again depends on OEM and the Android version it is running. But by and large this is becoming increasingly difficult to do with OEMs and Android security features preventing this

Without rooting , if you wish to back up (not Nandroid) see this [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553)